# What are the tax implications for transferring money to friend from UK to India?

Tags: india, gift-tax

The money is a large amount and it is for a fiance to be transferred from UK to India? The money still be treated as gift if the parties get married within the year?

Answer (score 1):

Best consult a CA.
There is no clear guideline on this. Some [articles](http://articles.economictimes.indiatimes.com/2014-01-24/news/46562979_1_basic-tax-exemption-tax-rebates-income-tax-act) do suggest that if engaged and planning to marry, one can transfer money to fiancée without any tax implication.